# Insert into multiple(7) tables with no duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to create a query/SP that will take data from one table and insert it into multiple tables. I have one main table that everything is put into at the beginning like a temp table.

**Temp table**

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
 (
  userID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
  userName VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
  FirstName VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  LastName VARCHAR(50) NUll,
  UserPassWd VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
  EmailId VARCHAR(100) NULL 

  CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY (userID)
 )
```

Than when employee is verified it will be split up into multiple tables that only need a field or two from the temp table as needed. The `UserEmail` table I have listed below is one of the tables. I'm trying to get it to work for one table right now and then I'm guessing i will just copy the insert part and change the table name and attributes to the new tables

Here is what i have so far.

```
DECLARE @EMAIL VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @USERID INT

SELECT   @USERID = userID 
        ,@EMAIL =  EmailId

FROM    Employee

WHERE   userID = 1004


INSERT INTO UserEmail
    (
        EmailAddress    
       ,EmailTypeID     
       ,ExternalUserID
       ,Active
       ,CreatedByID
       ,CreatedDate
       ,UpdatedByID
       ,UpdatedDate

    )

SELECT  @EMAIL  -- Email Address
    ,1          -- Email Type                   
    ,1          -- ExternalUserID
    ,1          -- Active
    ,1          -- CreatedByID
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -- CreatedDate
    ,1
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -- UpdatedDate

FROM    Employee X

WHERE   1=1
        AND X.userID = '####'-- INSERT USERID HERE for testing
```

This will insert the record into the `UserEmail` table but will create duplicate users, which i cant have so I tried adding this but it doesn't do what I want it to do.

`WHERE 1=1
        AND NOT EXISTS( 
                        SELECT userID
                        FROM   Employee
                        WHERE  userID = 1004
                )`

Any guidance or help would be much appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: How about simply adding DISTINCT to your query?

Comment: That's a good idea, ill give it a go.

Comment: I don't understand a lot of your script. You have a table, from which you need to insert certain values to different tables, then why not simply use a `insert into UserEmail SELECT`? Why all the variables? `EmailId` is not in the `Emplyee` table, how can you select it into `@EMAIL`? Why doesn't the table `UserEmail` have an attribute that links to a `user`? Also, why do you store dates as an integer? And finally, what do you consider a duplicate? You are really only inserting `EmailId`, the rest is just defaults, is it really an `EmailId` or an `EmailAddress`?

Comment: `DISTINCT` may help, but you are way better of if you can first identify **why** you have duplicates in the first place. Although I wouldn't even know *where* you are supposed to put the `DISTINCT`; in the query where you set the variables? That doesn't matter, since variables can only hold one value. In the last select used in the insert? Shouldn't matter, since you are limiting that select by a single `userID`, which is the primary key, so can't give more than one row.

Comment: I think the final crux is what do you mean by `duplicate users`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger ok im fixing some of what you said in your first comment, but as for duplicate users or ids.. Im referring to when a users info, in this case the EmailId/EmailAddress is taken from the `Employee` table it isn't entered into the `UserEmail` table more than once if the Query is ran multiple times.

Comment: That's simply a matter of the correct primary/foreign keys and perhaps other constraints. Or, but less advised, you could add a where clause to prevent that from happening

Comment: Ill post the where clause that I've been working on but have no sucess.

Answer (score 2):

If you only like NOT to insert to `UserEmail` if user already exists just extend

```
INSERT INTO UserEmail ....
   SELECT ....
   FROM ....
   WHERE ..
      AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from UserEmail where EmailAddress = X.emailAddress)
```

Otherwise review `MERGE` syntax (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql)

Comment: This clears up what was wrong with my `NOT EXIST` where clause, thank you. Im looking into the `MERG` syntax now.